# Development of Software for a client by using Open source Operating System

Tags: development, license, gpl

the software develop on Ubuntu Operating system also came under the GPL Sanctions ??
for example

1. I Install Ubuntu Operating system
2. I Install Visual studio code for development any software for a customer
3. I do not use any source code from GPL for the software development.
4. now shall i need to open my source code as it is the property of client who paid me
5. Can you please guide me under what circumstances we need to place the source code of the software if we use open source Operating System?

Comment: I think the key is #4.  The software you developed is/was a product paid for by a client.  That means you, as the vendor, must have signed a contract with the client.  So, it depends on what the client and you have agreed upon.  Certainly just by using Ubuntu alone isn't enough to say that your work must be open source.  Only if you modify and re-distribute the Ubuntu source code do you have to worry about that.  Anyway, work out issue #4 with your client -- as you clearly state, it is their property since you made it for them.

Comment: Ok, but my software which will be develop on Ubuntu Operating System is using the Linux Kernel which is licensed by GNU General Public License. and my software will use the system calls of the Linux kernel to run on the Ubuntu Operating system. now what will be the GNU General public license will say about such software. shall i use some other license. Conclusion of the Question: The software which will be develop on Open source Operating system and run on open source operating system will also fall under the license of GNU GPL

Comment: I think you're over-thinking this a bit too much...  Another way of thinking about this is can Ubuntu and the Linux kernel be used to develop commercial software?  And the answer is yes.  The GPL license refers to what you can or cannot do with the modification or distribution of the software itself.  So, if you modify the kernel and re-distribute.  But they don't stipulate what you must do with software that's made using them (i.e., in already compiled form).  You might want to acknowledge Ubuntu and Linux in your product, but that's a courtesy and not a requirement.

Comment: Since you're so concerned, is there something in the end-user licensing agreement in Ubuntu that worries you?  Perhaps you can put up the clause that concerns you and someone can help you better?

Comment: @Ray I agree but not agree because there are many clients who develop the software for their bushiness use and those business may extend globally and the dealing may extends up to million dollars or less so I need to give the customer satisfaction in any case

Comment: This is a user support site, and not a legal-advice site.  https://ubuntu.com/legal

Comment: @Harris Indeed, the users in this site aren't in a position to give you legal advice.  If you need it, you should spend the money on a lawyer and ask him/her.  Similarly, if you want to debate with me (or someone else) about the morality or legality of using Ubuntu to develop commercial software, that's also a separate topic.  Is there something in the EULA of Ubuntu that you don't understand?  If you understand but don't agree with it, you should take it up with someone else somewhere else...

Comment: @24601 No, that's a separate topic.  If you're a vendor for a client, then it comes down to what you two agreed to.  And that has nothing to do with Ubuntu.  What the OP is talking about is using Ubuntu to develop software; whether that has to be made open.

Comment: Thanks for your answers i will definitely seek for the lawyer and discuss this issue with them but before proceeding further i want to know does lawyer know the technical information of the software that how the software is working weather the software  is using the any dynamic libraries of the operating system  which is under General Public license or the software is dependent on open source operating system which is under General public license or Software is using the the source module of the source code which is protected by GPL ??

Comment: one more thing is there any way to Contact to General Public License and open source foundation through Email ??? or how shall i contact with them and once again thanks for considering my questions and give me your precious time to answer me

Comment: Correction:
Thanks for your answers i will definitely seek for the lawyer and discuss this issue with them but before proceeding further i want to know does lawyer know the technical information of the software that how the software is working 1- weather the software is using  any dynamic libraries of the operating system which is under General Public license 2- the software is dependent on open source operating system which is under General public license

Comment: Reamingin comment : 3- Software is using the the source module of the source code which is protected by GPL 4- The software is develop on Open source Operating System which is protected by General public license and is dependent on operating system to run

Comment: Ummmm, I don't know how to say this but a lawyer makes heaps of money per hour.  Yet I and anyone else replying here are doing it as volunteer work.  Given the amount of money you'll be paying, they better have the background to understand the question or else they have no right accepting you as a client...  And this is an `Ubuntu` support site that volunteers help out with.  I'm not sure if you can reasonably expect anyone here to explain to you or debate with you the GPL...  Clearly you haven't appreciated any of the time I've spent answering your question as you seem to just want more...

Comment: Thanks once again there is an ambiguity in this statement what is derivative and build on in GNU General Public License even tough i have wasted my time the statement in the GNU GPL is ambiguous they need to be clearly define it else people will start leaving their trust on open source Thanks once again